# Proof that the set of polynomial in $Z[x]$ with linear term coefficient equal to $0$ is a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Can anybody help me on that? I'm having trouble

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. How can a polynomial be a domain?

Comment: Just changed it, sorry

Comment: It suffices to show that this is a subring of the domain $\Bbb Z[X]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $R$ be the set in question. It is enough to prove $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb Z[x]$. It'll automatically be a domain. To prove that $R$ is a subring, it is enough to prove that it is closed under subtraction and multiplication, since it clearly contains $0$ and $1$. There is no need to check associativity etc, because these hold in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

All the above is generic. To actually prove something, you'll need to use the definition of $R=\mathbb Z + x^2 \mathbb Z[x]$ or as the set of all polynomials $f$ such that $f'(0)=0$.